# Autoincrement Primary keys as Foreign Key - Problems in Merging database

Tags: mysql

I have these situation where i have two databases(Same structure diff. data) and I want them to merge.
My problem is almost all tables used the autoincrement primary key as foreignkey so basically I cannot just export the data to the other.

My question is :

```
1. Is there any other way to do this except for data mine or manual?
2. To avoid this in the future can I just create my own foreign key (Is that ideal)?
```

Answer (score 0):

There many situations, and many resolutions. You can create php, ruby, python and etc. script to copy data and fix foreign key relations.

or just :

1. create temporary table, lets say we have table and table_tmp
2. insert whole data from second table to table_tmp
3. copy new data from table_tmp to table:

   INSERT INTO table VALUES (SELECT * FROM table_tmp WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table));

3.1 or copy whole data from table_tmp to table:

```
INSERT INTO table (field, names, except, id, field) VALUES (SELECT field, names, except, id, field FROM table_tmp);
```

** of course it's better to have some uuid field to keep unique identificator and have relations using this field to avoid having problems with foreign keys

** if any additional requirements needed plz write in comments I'll try to add solution